# XML Exception catch

Tags: .net, xml

I have a program that will read scripts, if i open new scripts with an older version of this software will catch an error: "There is an error in XML document(19,10)" and this cause i catch err as Exception. 
i want to keep this catch but i want to create another catch before this to catch this kind of error, when XML parse fail, I tried to use XMLException type but it will never catch the error and keep going to the general exception catch. 
any idea how to get the xml parse catch.

thank you

Comment: can you post some code and/or be more explicit please ?

Comment: When you look at the error in the debugger - what sort of `Exception` is being reported?  If it's only throwing a generic `Exception` (rather than more specific `XMLException` etc) then you're out of luck.  On the other hand a re-factor could trap the error when it happens (leaving other errors able to bubble out) or even drop whatever the assumption is that's causing the error.

Comment: when i look to the debugger this what i can see "There is an error in XML document(19,10)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a message appears whilst deserialization and its type as far as I remember is `InvalidOperationException`.

So just add an other one `catch(InvalidOperationException exception)` block and see whether it works for you.

BTW, real exception with more specific details should be in the InnerException property of an actual exception.